Newly spawned particles instantly destroyed after lifespan expires in a custom particle system script
I'm trying to create a particle system script from scratch. The problem is that I want to spawn particles and after a certain lifespan destroy them so it won't keep loading the memory with particles infinitly.
This is the Particle script. I set
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Particle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public Vector3 velocity;
    public Vector3 gravityAcceleration = new Vector3(0, -9.81f, 0);
    public float lifespan = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        velocity = new Vector3(Random.Range(-2f, 2f), Random.Range(-2f, 2f), Random.Range(-2f, 2f));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Update position and velocity
        velocity += gravityAcceleration*Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position += velocity*Time.deltaTime;

        // Decrease the lifespan of the particle
        lifespan -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (lifespan <= 0f && this.gameObject != null) 
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject); // Destroy particle when lifespan expires
        }
    } 
}

and this is the emitter script:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticleEmitter : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject particlePrefab; // This creates a reusable GameObsejt asset (prefab) to create and asign particles dynamically while the script runs.
    public float particleRate = 20f; // Particles created per second.
    public float timer = 0f; // Time interval between 2 particle creation cycles.
    //private List<GameObject> particles = new List<GameObject>(); // A list to store all the particles created so I can iterate and update/remove them.


    void CreateParticle() {
        GameObject particle = Instantiate(particlePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        //particles.Add(particle);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        
        if(timer >= 1f / particleRate) {
            CreateParticle();   
            timer = 0f;
        }

    }
}

In this example I have set the lifespan at 2 seconds and as you can see after 2 seconds all particles are destroyed, and after that all newly spawned particles are also destroyed instantly. It appears that this lifespan variable is shared between all particles, how can I make it unique for each particle?
example lifespan = 2 sec.

What is the error you get in the console?

It sounds like you need to set the particle emitter lifespan, not just kill the emitter#

Btw would be way easier to just use the delay parameter of Destroy(object, delay); .. also in general you might want to look into object pooling for this instead of instantiate and destroy a lot of objects

true but rather than remaking the emitter each time, why not just limit the lifespan of the actual emitted particles

Do you by accident also have a particle component on the emitter?

@derHugo Even so, you cannot explain why all particles were destroyed at the same time.

@shingo wasn't trying to ^^ it looks like of course there is something going on beyond the code snippets we got here .. to me almost looks like a scene reload...

@derHugo Yea, a scene reload makes sense.

@Kibsgaard the error I'm getting is MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object. Parameter name: data

@derHugo I created an empty game object, created the 'ParticleEmitter' script and added as a component, then I created another sphere gameObject and attached it to emitter's prefab, and then added the 'Particle' script as a component to this sphere object. That's all I did so far, Idk what scene reload is and how to fix it :')

In your ParticleEmitter script please place a private void OnDestroy(){ Debug.LogWarning("EMITTER DESTROYED!"); } and check what the stack trace says for that log message .. maybe it can tell you what is going on

Example:
Use coroutine to disable/destroy the Particle's gameObject after lifespan.
Remove from Update:
        lifespan -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (lifespan <= 0f && this.gameObject != null) 
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject); // Destroy particle when lifespan expires
        }

    void Start()
    {
        velocity = new Vector3(Random.Range(-2f, 2f), Random.Range(-2f, 2f), Random.Range(-2f, 2f));
        StartCoroutine(LifespanRoutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator LifespanRoutine() 
    {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(lifespan);
         Destroy(gameObject);
    }

P. S.
A better approach is to set up object pooling instead of instantiating. Why even use a custom particle system? MonoBehaviour is quite a large wrapper for particles.

It's for an asignment :'),  I will try object pooling as well! Thank you very much

no problem. remember to show appreciation by upvoting / marking solved so that other people can find the answer more easily. thanks for sharing and good luck with the assignment :)
